# Fastq issue concerning UTF8 in Python

Tags: python, utf-8, fastq

I am trying to work with Fastq files and had the following error:

```
    File "/apps/software/Python/3.5.1-intel-2015c/lib/python3.5/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]  
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I tried using io.open as used in other forums but then got the following error:

```
File "/apps/software/Python/3.5.1-intel-2015c/lib/python3.5/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: The file is apparently not encoded with UTF-8. You need to find out what it's encoded with. Does the source of the file maybe tell you? Is there some documentation, any metadata?

Comment: See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379403/problematic-questions-about-decoding-errors?noredirect=1#comment665779_379403

Comment: Unfortunately I'm very very new to all this, but since the source files I've been working with are Fastq's they really should be encoded with ASCII from what I understand. I did run some bash commands (eg grep, sed, awk etc) on them before inputing to my Python script, but didn't think that should change the encoding...

Comment: Maybe a `file` command on the input file can shed some light overt the kind of data you have.